# I can´t delete a certain node in my linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, nodes, circular-list

I have the next linked list:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>
using namespace std;

//Node class
class Node
{
public:
    string name;
    string age;

    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
    Node(string name, string age)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->age = age;
        this->next = NULL;
        this->prev = NULL;
    }
};
//Doubly circular Linked list class
class List
{
private:
    Node *first;
    Node *last;

public:
    List()
    {
        this->first = NULL;
        this->last = NULL;
    }

    void deleteNode(string name)
    {

        Node *start = this->first;

        if (start == NULL)
        {
            return;
        }
        Node *curr = start, *prev_1 = NULL;
        while (curr->name != name)
        {
            if (curr->next == start)
            {
                printf("\nList doesn't have node with value = %d", name);
                return;
            }
            prev_1 = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }

        if (curr->next == start && prev_1 == NULL)
        {
            (start) = NULL;
            free(curr);
            return;
        }
        if (curr == start)
        {
            prev_1 = (start)->prev;
            start = (start)->next;
            prev_1->next = start;
            (start)->prev = prev_1;
            free(curr);
        }
        else if (curr->next == start)
        {
            prev_1->next = start;
            (start)->prev = prev_1;
            free(curr);
        }
        else
        {
            Node *temp = curr->next;
            prev_1->next = temp;
            temp->prev = prev_1;
            free(curr);
        }
    }

    void add(string name, string age)
    {
        Node *node = new Node(name, age);
        if (this->first == NULL)
        {
            this->first = node;
            this->first->next = node;
            this->first->prev = node;
            this->last = node;
        }
        else
        {
            this->last->next = node;
            node->next = this->first;
            node->prev = this->last;
            this->last = node;
            this->first->prev = this->last;
        }
    }

    void print()
    {
        Node *aux;
        aux = this->first;
        while (aux != NULL)
        {
            cout << aux->name << ", " << aux->age<<endl;
            aux = aux->next;
            if (aux == this->first)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    List list;
    
    list.add("David", "25");
    list.add("James", "45");
    list.add("Charles", "78");
    list.add("Katty", "96");
    cout<<"List without delete any node"<<endl;
    list.print();
    //trying to delete a certain node
    list.deleteNode("David");
    cout<<"printing list without David because I deleted him above"<<endl;
    list.print();
    return 0;
}
```

In my function `deleteNode` I try to send a name to delete it from the linked list, but when in run my code it doesn't work, it only shows me the next:

```
List without delete any node
David, 25
James, 45
Charles, 78
Katty, 96
```

And my expected output would be:

```
List without delete any node
David, 25
James, 45
Charles, 78
Katty, 96
printing list without David because I deleted him above
James, 45
Charles, 78
Katty, 96
```

I don´t know what else to do, I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: Why are you calling `free` to deallocate a node that you allocated with `new` ?

Comment: Too many things wrong with that code.  When adding the first node to the list, the `next` and `prev` members of that node are both set pointing to itself, which will cause an infinite loop on a loop that attempts to traverse the list and reaches that node.   Also, your `deleteNode()` function uses `free()` to release nodes that are created with a `new` expression - which causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: `free(curr);` -- Do not learn C++ by guessing or using `C` code as a model.  In every good C++ book, usage of `new` is coupled with `delete`.  The `free` function is never mentioned (unless the book talks about `malloc`).  Also, instead of `NULL`, that should be `nullptr`.  And then `List()` constructor could be shortened considerably by doing this `List() : first{}, last{} ()` -- No need to type `this->`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fors starters, `free` is the wrong way to free a pointer allocated with `new`. Use `delete` instead.  Also, it's generally best to pass strings as const references.

Your deleteNode function looks really complicated.  Let me simplify it for you.  Tell me what you think of this:

```
    void deleteNode(const string& name)
    {

        Node *start = this->first;

        while ((start != nullptr) && (start->name != name))
        {
           start = start->next;
        }

        if (start == nullptr)
        {
            return;
        }

        Node* prev = start->prev;
        Node* next = start->next;

        if (prev != nullptr)
        {
            prev->next = next;
        }
        else
        {
           first = next;
        }

        if (next != nullptr)
        {
            next->prev = prev;
        }
        else
        {
           last = prev;
        }
        delete start;
    }
```

Likewise, `add` can be simplified to just:

```
    void add(const string& name, const string& age)
    {
        Node *node = new Node(name, age);
        
        if (this->last == NULL)   // first insert
        {
            first = node;
            last = node;
        }
        else
        {
            last->next = node;
            node->prev = last;
            last = node;
        }
    }
```

Comment: where do you instance head and tail?

Comment: Oops... I meant `first` and `last`.... let me clean that up in a second.

Comment: Ok, I just corrected that. Let me know if you see any more typos.

Comment: thanks, It worked nice, just one thing, can you explain why `const string& varName` instead of `string varName`? thanks...

Comment: Pass by value incurs a copy of the string. Whereas pass by const reference passes the actual string instance without a copy.